# Mocked axios "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, axios, jestjs

I developing my final project using React with TypeScript and I'm trying to test a mocked response using Jest but I just get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

```
  25 |         }
  26 |
> 27 |         axios(requestConfig)
     |         ^
  28 |         .then(res => res.data)
  29 |         .then(data => {
  30 |             if(mounted) {
```

This is the code of the testing:

```
jest.mock('axios');

describe("MyMethodsPage tests", () => {

    test("Methods loaded correctly", async () => {
        const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
        const mockedResponse: AxiosResponse = {
            data: [mockedMethodsList[0]],
            status: 200,
            headers: {},
            config: {},
            statusText: 'OK'
        };

        mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedResponse);
        render(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <MyMethodsPage />
            </BrowserRouter>
        );

        // Before fetching
        expect(screen.getByText(/Mis métodos/)).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText(/Cargando.../)).toBeInTheDocument();

        // After fetching
        expect(await screen.findByText(/Test/)).toBeInTheDocument();

    });
});
```

And this is the part of the code where the error appears:

```
export function useAuthFetch<T>(url: string, token: string, method: Method = "get", body?: T) {
    const [data, setData] = useState<T>();
    const [isPending, setPending] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true;

        let requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            method: method,
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/${url}`,
            data: body
        }

        axios(requestConfig)
        .then(res => res.data)
        .then(data => {
            if(mounted) {
                setData(data);
                setError("");
                setPending(false);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if(mounted) {
                if(axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
                    setPending(false);
                    setError(error.response?.data.detail);
                } else {
                    setPending(false);
                    setError('Algo ha ido mal, inténtelo de nuevo más tarde');
                }
            }
        })

        return function cleanup() {
            mounted = false;
        };
    }, [body, method, token, url]);

    return {data, isPending, error}
}
```

If I do not add jest.mock and all the mocked part it works but I would like to not be calling the API while testing. Also it works in the "normal" environment, it is just in this case when it fails. I have tried adding a auth token manually but it still fails so I just have run out of ideas.

I have more tests with the same structure and all of them pass.

If you need more information I would give it to you (this is my first question in stackoverflow), thank you for your help.